# Using Python dictionary to filter unique matches in a pandas df

Tags: pandas, filtering

I have a df like so:

```
df = DataFrame({'CODE': ['AB12', 'AB12', 'CD12', 'CD12', 'CD14', 'CD14'], 'DATE': ['2021-02-01', '2021-03-06', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-06', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-06'], 'VALUE':[0,4,5,5,0,0]})

CODE    DATE        VALUE
AB12    2021-02-01   0
AB12    2021-03-06   4
CD12    2021-02-01   5
CD12    2021-03-06   5
CD14    2021-02-01   0
CD14    2021-03-06   0
```

I need to be able to extract very specific pairs of records from the original df, based on `CODE` and `DATE`.

So, my final output should look like this:

```
CODE    DATE    VALUE
AB12    2021-02-01  0
CD12    2021-03-06  5
CD14    2021-03-06  0
```

I did some research and figured that I could make it work by using a dictionary like the below:

```
my_filter = {'CODE':['AB12','CD12','CD14'], 'DATE':['2021-02-01','2021-03-06','2021-03-06']}
```

And then filtering by using:

```
res = df[df.isin(my_filter).sum(1) == 2]
```

The problem is that when I try this, the result just seems to return all possible combinations of `CODE` and `DATE`, presumably because it is evaluating whether either of the values in CODE or DATE are present in each instance.

```
res

    CODE    DATE    VALUE
0   AB12    2021-02-01  0
1   AB12    2021-03-06  4
2   CD12    2021-02-01  5
3   CD12    2021-03-06  5
4   CD14    2021-02-01  0
5   CD14    2021-03-06  0
```

How can I create a dictionary to pair each `CODE` with the corresponding `DATE` only?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `merge`:

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(my_filter), on=['CODE','DATE'])
```

Output:

```
   CODE        DATE  VALUE
0  AB12  2021-02-01      0
1  CD12  2021-03-06      5
2  CD14  2021-03-06      0
```